# NEHotspotHelper NetworkExtension

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, networkextension

I am trying to use the new framework but I can not understand very well the scope.

Is it possible to connect a `Wi Fi` automatically?
For example, when iOS call the background service in my App I can set the password and the confidence of a particular network.

```
[network setConfidence:kNEHotspotHelperConfidenceHigh];

[network setPassword:@"QWERTY"];
```

and I can see a message under the `SSID` but the user has to touch the Wi Fi to connect.

My question is, is It possible to do this without the user touch it? For example, When you have a known `Wi Fi` the `iOS` is connected to this automatically.

is There a way to emulate this behavior with this framework?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This framework only allows you to connect selecting the network (touching it).
You can´t emulate this behavior because you can´t get into settings app, it´s the extension that get into your app and do the work

Answer (score 0):

If the user has already previously connected to an SSID that you are managing through NEHotspotHelper, you can automatically connect them.  If the user has never connected to the SSID in the past, or has chosen to "Forget the Network", then know you can't automatically connect them without the user manually selecting the network from the settings app.

Like Fernando Garcia Corrochano said there is no way to emulate this behavior.